# VSCode launch program error with C language

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAxrp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMnYi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei0YA.png)

Can someone please help ? I am getting this program not found error with C language. I have been googling for the past 2 weeks and came across bazillions of questions and solutions for this error including on this platform itself but nothing seems to work for me.

Just started with learning programming and really frustrated with not being able to proceed.
I am literally on the verge of giving up and sticking with codeblocks.

Just please, someone sincerely help me if possible.

Comment: "I am literally on the verge of giving up and sticking with codeblocks"  Judging by the high volume of newbie questions regarding linker problems with VS Code, that sounds like an excellent plan. I really don't know why some (Microsoft?) are pushing for this IDE as a beginner-friendly one, it clearly is not. If you are expected to manually tweak som JSON, then that alone is proof of beginner(user)-unfriendliness.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question is not clear. If you can include the files in the folder and your tasks.json that would be ideal.

But from the error, one thing can be assumed is that your launch json is not able to find the hello.exe program. You either first need to generate it using  C compiler or use the "preLaunchTask" in launch json, which points to one of the defined tasks in tasks.json.

P.S. You need to first go through the basics of debugging in VS-Code, then hopefully you will not run through problems like this.